# Clickable JButton in JTable, and want to know the row they have clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecelleditor

I have a JButton inside a JTable in the last column, and when client click on that, It will show a JFrame. But I don't know how I can get the row so I can get the object in the row and send it to JFrame constructor?

it is my table:

```
table = new JTable(model);
    JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
    tableHeaderRenderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    tableHeader.setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
        private JLabel label;
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (selectedColumn == value) {
                label = (JLabel) tableHeaderRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                        value, true, true, row, column);
                label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(label.getBorder(), 
                          BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0)));
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            } else {
                label = (JLabel) tableHeaderRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                        value, false, false, row, column);
                label.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(label.getBorder(), 
                          BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 0)));
                label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            }
            return label;
        }
    });
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            JButton button = Shorter.button("Details", true);
            buttonPanel.add(button);
            return buttonPanel;
        }
    });
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new TableCellEditor() {
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {return false;}
        public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject arg0) {return false;}
        public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {}
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject arg0) {return true;}
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {return null;}
        public void cancelCellEditing() {}
        public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {}
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
                boolean arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            return null;}
    });
```

when frame loaded I want to know which row selected to add to frame constructor...

Comment: Show some code. What have you tried already?

Comment: I added my table code, I think I should edit my data... do you think so?

Comment: @sharp simple and short question, for why reason you create a new JFrame invoked from TableCellEditor, please whats real goal, this code doesn't help me somehow,

Comment: start with  [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) by @camickr, simple, clear code without side effects

Comment: I want to show a few details about message or letters in table and when client clicks on details the frame will show him full message or full letter details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't know how I can get the row so I can get the object in the
>   row and send it to JFrame constructor?

there are three choices

1. event from `JButton inside a JTable in the last column` must to returs proper coordinates from `JTables view`, you have to convert view to model in the case that `JTables view` is

   - sorted
   - filtered
   - column(s) is/are reordered
   - column(s) is/are hidden (removed from JTables view)
2. (and/or with) add `ListSelectionListener` to `JTable`
3. `Mouse Events` can returns that too, read official `Oracle tutorial How to use Tables - Specifying Tool Tips for Cells` for working code example

Comment: I think when I am going to add buttons to data, I should add actionlisteners to them, but now I cannot test it because my code is not completed yet. do you think it will work or not? and why?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple `ButtonColumn` some time ago, I think it can help you a little, but as @mKorbel mentioned, you must to solve problems with sorting,filtering etc.

.

```
public class ButtonColumn extends AbstractCellEditor 
    implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor{

    private JButton button;
    private String value;

    public ButtonColumn(){
        button = new JButton();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("pressed"+value);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
            boolean arg2, boolean arg3, int arg4, int arg5) {
        button.setText(arg4+"");
        value = " "+arg4;
        return button;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable arg0, Object arg1,
            boolean arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        button.setText(arg3+"");
        value = " "+arg3;
        return button;
    }
}
```

Set it to your column in next way:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(YOUR_COLUMN_NUMBER).setCellEditor(new ButtonColumn());
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(YOUR_COLUMN_NUMBER).setCellRenderer(new ButtonColumn());
```

Comment: 1. something happends with engine for code tag, today I see that a few times, 2. not sure if this is way to go :-), AFAIK because JTable knows its column & row's coordinates,

Comment: I put there again code tag and formatting manually by deleting spaces on 1st and last line, normally I'd have to advertise this issue on meta SO, but my endless lazyness ....

Comment: I do that like this: JButton[] buttons = new JButton[messages.size()];
  for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
   buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
     ViewMessage frame = new ViewMessage(messages.get(Messages.this.i));
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
   });
  }
  for(int i=0; i<messages.size(); i++){
   data[i][0] = messages.get(i).getSubject();
   data[i][1] = messages.get(i).getSender();
   data[i][2] = dateText;
   data[i][3] = buttons[i];
  }

Comment: for what you do that code? I can't understand. if you want different listeners for all rows, try to remove listeners from button and add new for current line.

Comment: how can I do that? I find some code in this site, but when I run that and I click on a row the listener run twice and I don't know why? do you have any idea about this or can you give me an example code? I really confused using tables in java :|

Comment: You can do that like this : `for(ActionListener l : button.getActionListeners()){
button.removeActionListener(l);}
button.addActionListener(getActionListenerForRow(arg4));` but why you can't use one listener with different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/?trashed=1&ids=2322) for a solution that provides you with the row. All you need to do is provide it with an `Action`.